# What is the best way to store a IP flow tuple in JAVA?

Tags: java, network-programming

I am new to Network Programming. I have a task to store a source IP and port and Destination IP and port in a container in JAVA.

I am not able to find a good solution to it.

I am thinking of doing the following

```
Map<Inet4Address, port> SourceMap;
Map<Inet4Address,port> DestMap;
TreeMap<Map<Inet4Address, port> , Map<Inet4Address, port> > tupleMap;
```

Is this a good of storing tuples and iterating over them or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two `InetSocketAddresses` will do it. Each one holds an IP address and a  port.

Your maps don't make much sense. They would only allow for one connection to or from each IP address.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.